# How to convert org.jdom.Document to String

Tags: java, xml, jdom

How do I to convert an org.jdom.Document to a String in Java?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
new XMLOutputter().outputString(doc);
```

Answer (score 15):

I got the answer myself

```
XMLOutputter xmOut = new XMLOutputter(); 
System.out.println("----" + xmOut.outputString(doc));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as well do like this with StringWriter

```
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    new XMLOutputter().output(doc, writer);
    System.out.println(writer.toString());
```